# Full screen background images scaling in IE11 strange behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I stumble upon a strange behavior on one off my websites. The website makes use of superbgimage.js jquery script, which scales an image fullscreen and is part of a slider.

Now on Chrome and Firefox the images are scaled as expected (mostly scaled down as i make the images intentially a little bigger). The images are not looking scaled in IE11. The strange thing is when i hit F12 (to see developersmode) and hit F12 again, the images are scaling correctly in IE11.
This only occurs when F12 developers window is pinned not when the developers window is "free floating". So i guess it has to do with the browser height in IE11 not the same on initialize and after hitting F12

I already have

```
img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also my application acts strangely in IE11. It's a mess. CSS does not work well and every thing is displaced.

Comment: One suggestion I have: show us your code. Find the minimum example that shows the problem behaviour, and add the code to your question.

Comment: If it works in Chrome and Firefox it most likely works in IE11. nd like Matt said share some code.

Comment: I'm having a possibly-related issue with IE scaling videos (deployed using the HTML5 video tag) on IE11 (on Windows 7).